# regexp как выбрать всё, кроме символов входящих в паттерн

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Смысл таков. Я хочу удалять все запрещенные символы из input[type='text'].
Я хочу делать это через стандартную ф-цию js - replace.

```
const pattern = /[a-zA-Z0-9._]+/gm;
console.log(inputValue.replace(pattern, ''));
```

Мне нужно удалить все символы, которые не входят в мой диапазон [a-zA-Z0-9._]
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это возможно реализовать?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Iwx7x4/1

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg спасибо, я только что думал об этом символе!) И сразу ты ответил, все работает, благодарю!)